# PDO PhP - Delete query from selecting ID

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to make it so when i click a "x" it will delete the entire row. 
I've linked each record to my jobRef however the delete isn't working.

This is what i've got so far;

```
<?php
$status = 'available';
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobStatus = "' . $status . '"');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo "<table><tr><td>Job Reference</td><td>Description</td>";
foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['jobRef']."</td>","<td>".$row['jobDescription']."</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['jobRef']."'>Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

Heres my delete.php

```
<?php
require 'mysqlcon.php';

?>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query1= ("DELETE FROM person WHERE id='$id'");
if($query1)
{
header('location:Vacancies.php');
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply write your query , Forget to execute it.

```
$query1= ("DELETE FROM person WHERE id='$id'");
```

You need to execute it

```
$pdo->query("DELETE FROM person WHERE id='$id'");
```

Or better to use bind statement

```
$sth =$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM person WHERE id=:id');
    $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $count = $sth->rowCount();
    if($count>0)
    {
        header('location:Vacancies.php');
    }else{
        echo "Error in delete";
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::query1() in /srv/http/delete.php on line 11

Comment: <?php
require 'mysqlcon.php';

?>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sth =$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id=:id');
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
if($sth)
{
header('location:Vacancies.php');
}
}
?>

Comment: It's not deleting row clicked "x" on. I used the first snippet to select jobRef and assign that to the "x".

Comment: echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['jobRef']."'>x</a></td><tr>";

Comment: are you able to get `id` using `$_GET['id'];`??

Comment: I assume so? If i click the "x" the page which loads is "root/delete.php?id=1"

Comment: Nothing, It simply loads my vacancies page. Doesn't delete a row

Comment: Perhaps i should sleep, Overlooked the delete statement. Works perfectly now. thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help!! enjoy